# What can I find an authoritative statement of the conditions for a valid Roman Catholic baptism?

Tags: catholicism, baptism

I am interested in knowing where to find an *authoritative statement* of the conditions that make for a valid baptism.

In particular, I'm looking for a statement that would provide, even if indirectly, the answers to the following:

- is the baptized person required to have reached a particular age?
- is the person doing the baptism required to have been baptised ... in the same way as formal ordination can only be carried out by someone who (as at least one necessary condition) has themselves been ordained?
- is the validity of the baptism dependent only on the actions
  performed during the baptism or also upon some aspect of the person
  performing the baptism?

Answer (score 4):

**What are the conditions for a valid Roman Catholic baptism?**

Basic recognized baptisms in the Catholic Church must have the following:

> [**Requirements for baptismal validity**](http://rcchurch.com/uploads/Baptism_Guidelines_web.pdf)
>
> In brief, what is required for baptismal validity is:
>
> 1. Correct matter and form:
>
> a. Application of water – whether by pouring or by immersion.
>
> b. Use of the Trinitarian formula. The minister declares that the person is being baptized **“in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit.”** This must be pronounced by the same person who administers the water, and at the same time. Inserting additional words or deliberately modifying the Trinitarian formula may invalidate the baptism.
>
> 2. Intent of the minister to do what the Church does (this does not necessarily mean holding the Catholic doctrine of baptism).
> 3. Intent/consent of the baptized (if an adult).
>
> Thus, some factors that would invalidate a baptism include:
>
> • The use of a substance other than water (cf. 1a).
>
> • The use of sprinkling, when the water does not clearly touch the skin of the person being baptized. (cf. 1a).
>
> • The use of a formula which changes or omits the names of the Persons of the Trinity, such as “I baptize you in the name of the Creator, the Redeemer, and the Sanctifier”4 (cf. 1b).
>
> • Having one person pour the water while another person pronounces the words of the formula (cf. 1b).
>
> • Baptism in a community whose beliefs are so far removed from Trinitarian faith (e.g., Mormonism) that the minister does not truly intend Christian baptism (cf. 2).
>
> • A lack of consent to be baptized on the part of someone who has reached the age of reason (cf. 3).

The Catechism of the Catholic Church explains that in an emergency anyone can baptize someone validly, even someone not baptized may validly baptize another when in danger of death.

> [**V. Who can Baptize?**](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p2s2c1a1.htm)
>
> **1256** The ordinary ministers of Baptism are the bishop and priest and, in the Latin Church, also the deacon. In case of necessity, anyone, even a non-baptized person, with the required intention, can baptize , by using the Trinitarian baptismal formula. The intention required is to will to do what the Church does when she baptizes. The Church finds the reason for this possibility in the universal saving will of God and the necessity of Baptism for salvation.

Keep in mind that the trinitarian formula for a valid baptism must be as follows: **I baptize you in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit.** The phrase “we baptize you” will invalidate a baptism, so do not employ it! See [here](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2022/feb/16/arizona-baptisms-invalidated-priest-uses-one-wrong-word).

Baptism of infants can be administered at any moment after birth by any Catholic priest or deacon when a convenient time can be made. Many infant baptisms in past centuries were administered as soon as possible after birth when child mortality was greater.

Canon Law extends baptism when and if possible to abandoned infants and aborted fetuses that are still living.

> [Can. 870](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/eng/documents/cic_lib4-cann834-878_en.html) An abandoned infant or a foundling is to be baptized unless after diligent investigation the baptism of the infant is established.
>
> Can. 871 If aborted fetuses are alive, they are to be baptized insofar as possible.

Hope this helps and God Bless.

Comment: Perhaps noting that apparently ‘I baptize you ...’ is necessary and ‘we baptize you ...’ may be invalid: see https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2022/feb/16/arizona-baptisms-invalidated-priest-uses-one-wrong-word

Answer (score 0):

The answer was easier to find than I had imagined it would be; certainly more easily than when I tried several years ago to discover it.

The requirements for baptism are described authoritatively in the [Code of Canon Law](https://www.vatican.va/archive/cod-iuris-canonici/cic_index_en.html); specifically, Book IV Function of the Church (Cann. 834 - 848), Part 1, The Sacrements; Title 1. Baptism (Cann. 849 - 878).

Comment: Welcome! Stack Exchange has an expression "[Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370)" Please write an answer in this castle.

Comment: I think that the answer is firmly "in this castle". The question opens with the words, "Where can I find an authoritative statement ...". Having a recitation of the conditions of baptism might be good, but it is not inherently authoritative. In contrast, the Code of Canon Law is an authoritative statement of the required conditions . Perhaps more importantly, the link given is useful but not critical; the reference for the authoritative source is stated in full.